# What is the Linux equivalent of this environment variable, originating from windows?

Tags: linux, windows

`set __COMPAT LAYER=RunAsInvoker`

What is the linux equivalent, if existing?

Comment: What is this code supposed to do other than set an environmental variable? As asked, I suppose you could do `export __COMPAT='LAYER=RunAsInvoker`. It is then up to the application to decide what to do with the variable.

Answer (score 2):

Running "as invoker" means basically "ignore any hints that the application needs admin privileges", so it just suppresses the UAC dialog and pretends you rejected running as admin (but starts the application nonetheless).

There is no direct equivalent because there is no UAC dialog -- the closest you could get is to run the program through the binary interpreter instead of directly, which would ignore any set-user-id bits on the binary (i.e. the app runs with lower privileges than it would normally). Find out the interpreter, e.g. using `file`:

```bash
$ file /usr/games/sl 
/usr/games/sl: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, …
```

Then running

```bash
$ /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/games/sl
```

... will run it as your user, regardless of whether the suid flag is set on the binary.

Comment: Ritcher it is not working I used file program path

Comment: @jastyles "_it is not working_" tells us nothing. What happened? What didn't happen? What was supposed to happen? You are our eyes on this - tell us what you see!

Comment: Shared library error